# carrierwave: creating version based on image properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I want to keep my uploaded images upto 700 pixels.
If any image gets bigger I use the following code to get a new width.

This is my uploader file.

```
def store_dimensions
if file && model
  width, height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
        if width>700
              return 700
        else
              return width
        end
end
```

Then I created a version named best_fit

```
process :store_dimensions
version :best_fit do
  process :resize_to_fill => [store_dimensions,200]
end
```

It can't find the store_dimensions method. On the other hand, if I use self keyword while declaring store_dimensions method, then it works, but then the "file" identifier is become an unknown entity.

How can I get the value of the uploaded image and according to that I can create a new version of it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code saved my ass today. I'm happy that I solved it.

```
def store_dimensions
     if file && model
      width, height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
        if width>700
              Rails.logger.info "#{width}"
              finalHeight=((700*height)/width)
              self.class.version :best_fit do
                process :resize_to_fill => [700,finalHeight]
              end

        else
              Rails.logger.info "#{width}"
              self.class.version :best_fit do
                process :resize_to_fill => [width,height]
              end
        end
      end
end

#run the store_dimensions methods
  process :store_dimensions
```

Comment: Almost! This has been a nightmare even 3 years on. Problem here is you cannot refer to the versions from the model when you attempt to present. After fighting for the last hour, I'd say the ideal approach is to define a custom process method and manipulate the image directly: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb

Answer (score 0):

For any lost wanderers, this is what you're looking for:

```
class Uploader
  version :my_version do
    process :my_processor
  end

  def my_processor
    # model is available here!

    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        cmd.resize [model.width, model.height].join('x')
      end

      img
    end
  end
end
```

Example of [custom process method](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb#L136)